# Non-linear regression with neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, non-linear-regression

How do you create an NN to solve for example: 2 * x ** 3 + 4 * x + 8 + random noise?
I can do this easily with LinearRegression from sklearn, but I'd like to be able to achieve this for a multivariate sample where I have no idea wether the function is log/exp/poly/etc.
Thank you!
Ashkan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonlinearity in Neural Network can be achieved by simply having a layer with a nonlinear activation function, e.g. (relu). For example:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape=(n_features,)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)
```

Just needed 3 more layers of these - thanks Tony!

Comment: relu is still somewhat linear (relu(x)=max(0, x)). there is no way it can see degree 3 of x.

Comment: @Ashkan with multiple layers it can

Comment: @NicolasGervais , it did after 10,000 epochs (4 layers of dense/relu). Thanks!